# Nginx CSP frame-src ignored

Tags: nginx, content-security-policy

I have an Nginx CSP configured as follows:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js;img-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com data:;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';frame-src 'self' https:;object-src 'self';connect-src 'self' ws:;media-src 'self'
```

When I try to load a page in Chrome I see:

```
Refused to frame 'https://myexternalwebsite.com/a/b/index.html' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

In my CSP frame-src is clearly set and has the values 'self' and https:

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you add "https:" to the default policy? frame-src is deprecated in CSP 2 so maybe Chrome is ignoring it?

Comment: Check headers that browser received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit strange but I managed to fix this by specifying:

```
frame-src 'self' *;
```

This satisfies my requirements.